# Continuous Box Rotate - CSS animation

Tags: css, css-animations

So am fairly new in CSS animation and I wanted to ask a question I created this box and it as a small box inside that rotates from top to bottom, right to left and alternate but am wondering how can I make that it rotates fully around continuously, from the point of origin.
I tried setting the transform translateX to -232% once it reach back at the point of origin but end up not going back to its origin as intent.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<style>
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-size: 1.22rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.parent {
    background: #aed4ff;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.child {
    background-color: rgb(143, 36, 36);
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    display: block;
}
.parent:hover .child {
    animation: left-to-right 2s ease-in-out forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@keyframes left-to-right {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
        color: red;
    }
    33% {
        transform: translateY(232%);
    }
    50% {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    66% {
        transform: translateX(232%) translateY(232%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(232%);
        background-color: black;
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another keyframe with `translateX(0)` at 100% to move the element back to the original position, and for the other "transform-keyframes" use 25%, 50% and 75% instead of 33%, 67% and 100%.

And of course `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` to keep it going round.

So that would be

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.22rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.parent {
  background: #aed4ff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgb(143, 36, 36);
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  display: block;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  animation: left-to-right 3s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@keyframes left-to-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    color: red;
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(232%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(232%) translateY(232%);
    background-color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateX(232%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: am curious why do it this way

Comment: because you need it to return to the initial state before starting again

Comment: so wait all i need to do was add a extra one, set 100% to zero

Comment: wait am still kinda confused

Comment: can i get a more detail explanation please

Comment: what's unclear to you? Look at the example I added - the element moves four times/ways instead of three times (in your question code) to reach its original position before the animation starts again. In your own code, the animation stops after the third move, at a different position, so there's a sudden jump when the animation starts again.

Comment: yea thanks for the info i kinda figured it out during the time i didnt get a response

Answer (score 1):

You can set your animation to run continuously by adding this to your css

```
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
```

Comment: yeah i already know that but i want to go continuously around

Comment: instead of it jumping back to 0%